# Dynamic Kendo grid columns from response data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have been trying to create a Kendo grid with dynamic column values based on a date item as part of the response data.

The data I have looks like this:

```
[
    { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 1000},
    { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 2000},
    { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 3000},
    { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 1400},
    { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 2000},
    { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 5000}
]
```

My intended structure for the grid is the following:

```
| Name |  Jan | Feb  | Mar  |
|------|------|------|------|
| Foo  | 1000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| Bar  | 1400 | 2000 | 5000 |
```

I had a look at https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/various/create-with-dynamic-columns-and-data-types but it was not quite what I was trying to do and it required that I have the columns sent as part of the response.

I am working with a wrapper for GridOptions that populates the columns through a staticly defined json. Since my columns are dynamic I am having an issue with defining them there.

On top of that, I am unable to pick out the values for the date besides brute forcing through the values and storing all the unique date entries as columns. And if I have them, then how do I match them up with the correct data entry to display the correct value in the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you.
I made a dojo for you and pasted the code bellow for the future.
I used the possibility of having a callback transport for the read.

https://dojo.telerik.com/imeNOdUh/2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="my-grid"></div>

  <script>

    function fetchData(success, fail) {
        success([
        { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 1000},
        { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 2000},
        { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 3000},
        { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 1400},
        { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 2000},
        { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 5000}
      ]); 
    }    

    var $gridElement = $('#my-grid');
    $gridElement.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
            read: function(options) {

              fetchData(function(data) {

                // get month names
                var monthNames = data
                    .map(function(t) {
                    var monthName = kendo.format("{0:MMM}", kendo.parseDate(t.Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'));
                    return monthName;
                  })
                    .reduce(function(p, t) {
                        if (p.indexOf(t) == -1)
                        p.push(t);

                        return p;                        
                  }, []);

                // transform
                var result = data.reduce(function(p, t) {
                    var monthName = kendo.format("{0:MMM}", kendo.parseDate(t.Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'));

                  var existing = p.filter(function(t2) {
                    return t2.Name == t.Name;
                  });

                  if (existing.length) {
                    existing[0][monthName] = t.Value;
                  } else {
                    var n = {
                        Name: t.Name
                    };
                    monthNames.forEach(function(m) {
                      n[m] = 0;
                    });

                    n[monthName] = t.Value;
                    p.push(n);
                  }

                  return p;
                }, []);

                options.success(result);

              });


            }
          }
        }
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the kendo ui `PivotGrid` component.  It is built for dealing with categorical data. However, you probably would find that takes up to much real estate.

That leaves the task of manually pivoting the data yourself.  A task that is relatively simple if you make the assumptions that the `Date` values over all the data never have a month from two different years (If there was a 01-01-2018 and 01-01-2017 they are both Jan) and the is only one row for each date/name combo.  (If there were two values for a date/name you would have to decide what is done with the value? min, max, first, last, mean ?)

```
data = 
[
    { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 1000},
    { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 2000},
    { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Foo', Value: 3000},
    { Date: '01-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 1400},
    { Date: '02-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 2000},
    { Date: '03-01-2018', Name: 'Bar', Value: 5000}
];

// distinct month nums over all data
months = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
  var parts = item.Date.split('-');
  var month = parts[0] - 1;
  if (months.indexOf(month) == -1) months.push(month);
});

// sort and convert month num to month name (for columns)
months.sort();
months.forEach(function(monthNum,index,arr) {
  arr[index] = new Date(2018,monthNum,1).toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" });
});

function mmddyyyyToMon(mmddyyyy) {
  var parts = mmddyyyy.split("-");
  var jsMonth = parts[0] - 1;
  var jsDay = parts[1];
  var jsYear = parts[2];
  return new Date(jsYear,jsMonth,jsDay).toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" });
}

// helper to make sure pivot item has one field for every month observed over all data
function newPivotItem () {
  var result = { Name: '' };
  months.forEach(function(month) {
    result[month] = undefined;
  })
  return result;
}

// presume data grouped by Name and ordered by month within
var pivotData = [];
var pivotItem = {};
data.forEach (function (item) {
  var parts = item.Date.split("-");
  var jsMonth = parts[0] - 1;
  var jsDay = parts[1];
  var jsYear = parts[2];
  var month = new Date(jsYear,jsMonth,jsDay).toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" });

  if (pivotItem.Name != item.Name) {
    // start next group of data for a name
    pivotItem = newPivotItem();
    pivotData.push(pivotItem);
    pivotItem.Name = item.Name;
  }

  // set value for month for the name
  pivotItem[month] = item.Value;
})

console.log (pivotData);
```